# How do I log in and access Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, kde

I know it sounds like a dumb question, and problems should be addressed in the FAQ or the forum. But Ubuntu One seems to resist all attempts to actually log in and access its services.

Recap of what I've tried:

- I created an Ubuntu One account a long time ago, and I'd like to be able to access it.
- If I go the *sign in* or *sign up* link at the ubuntu one page, a blank page loads. Nothing happens.
- I re-installed Ubuntu 10.04 a short while ago. My choice of desktop environment is KDE. I did find [this page online](http://maketecheasier.com/how-to-install-and-setup-ubuntu-one-in-kubuntu/2010/03/15). But when I follow the instructions, my installation of `apt` can't find the repository.
- I found a page for another client, [KDE client for Ubuntu One](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client-kde), 
  but this product seems to be in early alpha, and it was released a long time ago.
- I fired up `nautilus`, but poking around, I can't seem to find a way to connect to an Ubuntu-One account.
- I fired up `gnome-panel`, and opened up the *preferences* for Ubuntu One.  When I click on `manage account`, I get a blank page.
- Looking at Ubuntu One's FAQ, I see that there is an article addressing problems logging in via the ***Gnome Ubuntu One Preferences Manager***, so I tried to follow the instuctions. It instructs to open the ***'password and encryption keys' manager*** from the gnome panel, and make changes to Ubuntu One settings. The entry I'm supposed to change is absent.

So, how do I actually access my account? Preferrably from KDE?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu One for Android, cant log into. Pressing log in but only get a message that there was an error. Cant even configure and type usr name or password. If i press register i am logged on to the website. But nothing in the app. Btw, everything works perfectly on computers @ home!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use Ubuntu One from KDE at this point, is probably to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.

- The Ubuntu One control panel is now based on Qt.
- The code is split up a bit better, and should be installable without requiring most of GNOME as it did before.
- The programs have had many performance improvements, as well as bug fixes.

The new `ubuntu-sso-client` used by Ubuntu One now, should work with the new KWallet API in newer versions of KDE as well. It uses the Freedesktop Secrets API to talk to the keyring. However, if KWallet doesn't support everything that `ubuntu-sso-client` uses yet, then `gnome-keyring` will still be required. You can install that package, and ensure that `gnome-keyring-daemon` is getting started when you log in, and the environment variables it sets, are exported to the applications in KDE. You can check that by running `env | grep GNOME_KEYRING` inside a terminal.

Once that's set up, you should be able to launch `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt`, and click the *Sign me in with an existing account* button to log in with your current account.

However, if you simply get a blank page when logging in on the web site, you may want to file a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ so that the support team can check your account is not having issues.